# How I install SFrame in Anaconda, I have tried but faile to install

Tags: python

Actully I am not getting proper guideline to install it.

I am expecting someone will guide me regarding this issue. If someone help me out it will be amazing for me. I am actually struggling with this issue. I am looking for someone who will help me in this issue.

Comment: Please provide some more information. How did you tried to install it?